# Induction without using the hypothesis?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction, proof-explanation

Let $\{a_n\}$ for $n \geq 1$ be a sequence of real numbers defined by the recurrence relation $a_1 > 3$ and $\frac{a_{n+1} \cdot (a_n + 1)}{a_n + 9} = 1$. Show that $a_{2n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$ is bounded below and decreasing.

My attempt:

You can see that $a_{2n-1} = \frac{a_{2n-2}+9}{a_{2n-2}+1}$.

Goal. Show that $a_{2n-1} \geq 3$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$ then $a_{1} > 3$ (this has been directly given in the problem).

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n-1} \geq 3$. We show that $a_{2(n+1)-1} \geq 3$.

$$a_{2n + 1} - 3 = \frac{a_{2n}+9}{a_{2n}+1} - 3 = \frac{\frac{a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 1} + 1} - 3 = \frac{5a_{2n-1} + 9}{a_{2n-1} + 5} - 3 = \frac{2a_{2n-1} - 6}{a_{2n-1} + 5} \geq 0$$

Goal. Show that $a_{2n-1} \geq a_{2n+1}$ $\forall n\geq 1$.

Base. Suppose $n = 1$. It is clear that $a_{1} > 3$ and $a_3 = \frac{5a_{1} + 9}{a_{1} + 5}$. So

$$a_{1} - a_{3} = a_{1} - \frac{5a_{1} + 9}{a_{1} + 5} = \frac{a_{1}^2 - 9}{a_{1} + 5} > 0$$

Inductive. Assume that $a_{2n-1} \geq a_{2n+1}$. We show that $a_{2n+1} \geq a_{2n + 3}$.

$$a_{2n + 1} - a_{2n + 3} =a_{2n + 1} - \frac{a_{2n+2}+9}{a_{2n+2}+1} = a_{2n + 1} - \frac{\frac{a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 1} + 9}{\frac{a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 1} + 1}  = a_{2n + 1} - \frac{5a_{2n+1} + 9}{a_{2n+1} + 5} = \frac{a_{2n+1}^2 - 9}{a_{2n+1} + 5} \geq 0$$

This follows from the fact that $a_{2n + 1} \geq 3$ as shown in the bounded below induction proof.

QED.

Firstly are these proofs correct? Secondly, in the second induction above I don't really use the inductive hypothesis that $a_{2n-1} \geq a_{2n+1}$. Is that ok or is that a mistake? Any assistance much appreciated.

Would a direct proof also work for the decreasing part?

Comment: Looks fine to me. An inductive proof in which the inductive hypothesis is not used in the inductive step is still valid, but that would mean that induction is not necessary in the first place (the argument in the inductive step will work as a direct proof)

Comment: @TippingOctopus So would a direct proof also work here? In particular, showing that it is decreasing for $n \geq 1$?